# Why would you use a verbs stem (as state-of-being) rather than the verb itself?

Tags: usage, nuances

Now, I'm not sure if this has been answered, I looked but couldn't find a proper answer... so I ask. :)

While I was [listening to this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GiYR74_V3Eo), I noticed the line 「空、翳{かげ}り」。Now, in the context of the song I of course understand what's being said (tho, 翳 was new to me), but I still don't quite understand why they would write 翳り、instead of 翳る or something like that?

This isn't the first time I've seen this of course, but I still don't quite understand why it's done; thus I ask.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2934/5010

Comment: Maybe related too? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/34407/why-is-this-sentence-not-separated/34409#34409

Answer (score 2, accepted):

翳り is the continuative form of the verb. in this form it gives the sense that there's more yet to be said.

Comment: So... the stem can mean that? Or is that not a stem of 陰る？

Comment: @Tirous To begin with, conjunctive/continuative/adverbial forms are not a word stem.  "Stem" in linguistics means a component that doesn't change by conjugation.