# What does おり mean in this sentence?

Tags: subsidiary-verbs, renyōkei

Is it from the verb 居る? If it's so, why is not it ております?

> 怪人による被害はこれまでにない規模の拡大を続けて**おり**、…

Comment: please don't cut the context.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14698/9831

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In very short: it is the humble form of いる.

To give a typical example, おる is mostly used when talking about your own actions and trying to be humble (for example when talking to a superior such as your boss at work, to a customer, etc). Find something about this topic [here](https://everything2.com/title/oru) or check the [wiki about Japanese honorific speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorific_speech_in_Japanese).

In your specific example, I believe the sentence continues with something you haven't written here. In fact, おる is in the "pre-masu" form which is often used in written language to connect to the next sentence. Refer to [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/34407/why-is-this-sentence-not-separated/34409#34409) for more details on this.

EDIT: So I made some research and I think your full sentence is in fact:

> 怪人による被害はこれまでにない規模の拡大を続けており、現在協会側で災害レベルを判別中との...

Is it correct?

So I think we can translate this as (until the comma): *the damage due to the (less literally, left by) the mysterious person (monster? Not sure what 怪人 is depending on the context) is expanding at an unprecedented scale*.